# OpenShift "Build failed because of post commit hook." on Build

Tags: git, redhat-enterprise-linux, svn, node.js, deployment

I have been trying to build and deploy a MEAN stack application using OpenShift. I have applied the template Node.js and MongoDB when I created my project. I cannot seem to find any resources to help me and have attempted to understand [this documentation](https://docs.openshift.com/online/dev_guide/builds/build_hooks.html) also trying the method of configuring a post commit hook to an existing project. The OC shell stated that I successfully "Updated" the post commit hook. But I am still getting this error. Plus, it takes 49 minutes to build, only to fail after dependencies are installed.

```
Cloning "CONFIDENTIAL" ...
    Commit: CONFIDENTIAL
    Author: CONFIDENTIAL>
    Date:   CONFIDENTIAL
---> Installing application source ...
---> Installing all dependencies
npm WARN notice [SECURITY] base64url has the following vulnerability: 1 moderate. Go here for more details: https://nodesecurity.io/advisories?search=base64url&version=2.0.0  - Run `npm i npm@latest -g` to upgrade your npm version, and then `npm audit` to get more info.
npm WARN notice [SECURITY] hoek has the following vulnerability: 1 moderate. Go here for more details: https://nodesecurity.io/advisories?search=hoek&version=2.16.3  - Run `npm i npm@latest -g` to upgrade your npm version, and then `npm audit` to get more info.
npm WARN notice [SECURITY] lodash has the following vulnerability: 1 moderate. Go here for more details: https://nodesecurity.io/advisories?search=lodash&version=4.17.5  - Run `npm i npm@latest -g` to upgrade your npm version, and then `npm audit` to get more info.
npm WARN notice [SECURITY] mpath has the following vulnerability: 1 moderate. Go here for more details: https://nodesecurity.io/advisories?search=mpath&version=0.3.0  - Run `npm i npm@latest -g` to upgrade your npm version, and then `npm audit` to get more info.
npm WARN meanauthapp@1.0.0 No repository field.

added 106 packages in 2928.818s
---> Building in production mode
---> Pruning the development dependencies
npm WARN meanauthapp@1.0.0 No repository field.

up to date in 0.679s
/opt/app-root/src/.npm is not a mountpoint
---> Cleaning the npm cache /opt/app-root/src/.npm
/tmp is not a mountpoint
---> Cleaning the /tmp/npm-*
Running post commit hook ...
sh: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Inappropriate ioctl for device
sh: no job control in this shell

> meanauthapp@1.0.0 test /opt/app-root/src
> echo "Error: no test specified" && exit 1

Error: no test specified
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
error: build error: container "CONFIDENTIAL" returned non-zero exit code: 1
```